# Extract records with duplicate field in Unix (without using uniq!)

Tags: unix, uniq

I have a text file consisting of a variable-length key field in field 1, and other data in field 2.  The fields are separated by the tab character ("\t").  The key fields contain spaces.  The file is sorted on the key field.

I'd like to filter this to create a file containing only those records with duplicate key fields (that is, field 1), with the additional niceness of separating the groups of records with a blank line.

e.g.

```
01001|XYZ ZY|\tFOO MAN CHU\n
01001|XYZ ZY|\tBAR BAZ\n

01001|ZZZYYYXX|\tYACKETY YACK\n
01001|ZZZYYYXX|\tBOBBITY BOP\n
01001|ZZZYYYXX|\tTESTING TESTING\n
```

...etc.  In other words, exactly what `uniq -d -D` would do if it provided any options for alternate field delimiters or variable length fields!

Is there some way of accomplishing this in a command using off-the-shelf Unix filters?

Comment: use `awk` and its ability to set variables, compare them, etc. ($0 is the whole current line, NR is the current line number, $1 ... $n are the current fields (ignoring the separators, which you can also change for input and for output), etc)

Answer (score 0):

try awk as olivier suggests, if on solaris use nawk instead:

```
awk -F '    '  '{arr[$1]++; next} 
               END{for(i in arr)
                   {if(arr[i]>1) {print i}}  } ' infile > keyfile 

awk -F '    '  'FILENAME=="keyfile" {arr[$1]=1;next}
              FILENAME=="infile"  
                   {if( $1 in arr){print $0}} ' keyfile infile > newfile
```

This can be made shorter but more confusing for an awk newbie.  The -F '  ' <- has a tab character between the ''.

```
awk -F '    '  'NR==FNR {arr[$1]++; next}                                  
              (NR>FNR && arr[$1]>1) {print} '   infile infile > newfile
```

Nastier to understand version